# Какая разница между каскадом селекторов с пробелом и без?

Tags: css

Какая **разница** между вложенностью селекторов **с пробелом и без?** `.selector1.selector2` **/** `.selector1 .selector2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.selector1.selector2` - элементы с двумя классами `selector1` и `selector2` (и, возможно, другими)

`.selector1 .selector2` - элементы с классом `selector2` где-нибудь внутри элементов с классом `selector1`

Answer (score 3):

В первом случае это будет выглядеть как:

```
<div class="selector1 selector2"></div>
```

Во втором:

```
<div class="selector1">
    <div class="selector2"></div>
</div>
```

Если писать селекторы без пробелов, то это будет **один** компонент с несколькими классами. Если с пробелами, то это **вложенность** элементов